# Why does type inference not work for object properties when a variable is reassigned to a new object?

Tags: typescript

Why does type inference not work for object properties when a variable is reassigned to a new object?

Example (TypeScript v3.4.5):

```
// compiles
let myVar: string | number;
myVar = '5';
console.log(myVar.length);

// compiles
let myObj1: {myProp: string | number} = {myProp: 5};
myObj1.myProp = '5';
console.log(myObj1.myProp.length);

// does not compile, emitting the following error:
// TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
// myt.ts(63,26): error TS2339: Property 'length' does not exist on type 'string | number'.
//   Property 'length' does not exist on type 'number'.
let myObj2: {myProp: string | number} = {myProp: 5};
myObj2 = {myProp: '5'};
console.log(myObj2.myProp.length);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what's happening here is that the rules for [narrowing upon assignment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/8010) only apply to values of [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types), for better or worse:

> An assignment (including an initializer in a declaration) of a value of type `S` to a variable of type `T` changes the type of that variable to `T` narrowed by `S` in the code path that follows the assignment.
>
> [snip]
>
> The type `T` narrowed by `S` is computed as follows:
>
> - If `T` is not a union type, the result is `T`.
> - If `T` is a union type, the result is the union of each constituent type in `T` to which `S` is assignable.

It has been [suggested to lift this restriction](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27706), but for now that's the way it is.

Also note that the type `A | B` is a union, while the type `{x: A | B}` is not.  Yes, `{x: A | B}` has a *property* whose type is a union type, but it is not itself a union type.

---

So let's look at what happens here:

```
let myObj1: { myProp: string | number } = { myProp: 5 };
```

Okay, that's assigning a value of a non-union type.  So we can expect no narrowing here.  Let's make sure:

```
myObj1.myProp.toFixed(); // error!
```

Yep, no narrowing happened.  Moving on:

```
myObj1.myProp = "5";
```

Okay, that's assigning a value of type `string | number`, a union type.  So we can expect narrowing here.  Let's make sure:

```
console.log(myObj1.myProp.length); // no error
```

Yep, narrowing.  And then the rest of it:

```
let myObj2: { myProp: string | number } = { myProp: 5 };
myObj2 = { myProp: "5" };
```

Those are both assigning values of non-union types... so, no narrowing:

```
myObj2.myProp.length; // error!
```

Yep, no narrowing.

---

So that's probably the canonical explanation for why this happens.  As for whether narrowing should happen for all assignments... if you feel it should, you might want to go to the [relevant Github issue, microsoft/TypeScript#27706](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27706) and give it a  or describe your use case if you think it's particularly compelling.

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//?ssl=13&ssc=1&pln=10&pc=1#code/DYUwLgBAtgngagQwE4C4IGcxIJYDsDmEAPhLgK5QBGISA3ALABQsiSEAvBAEQCsXDjAMYB7XOmGgAdMGH4AFC2TSQBMAAsAlAKahIsAPKUAVgEY0Ab2gwACkmEAHNJhwFipCtTYBfDhEuxbBzQeCC8BA2MTSQC7e0kwYQAxbAAPEAATOS0IAHociBo7JABCJgjTaJtY315+MphDCpiHZVU1Wlz84QBrBBgmHXArRoAmCytAxwwsPEIScioaUN9-KqCIELD60ZWJ2LRa0PCG4xHKydb8dQ68gqQi0sYgA)